# One form 2 submit buttons 2 actions

Tags: php, forms, submit, action

I have a form. Form has 1 action and 1 submit button. If I press submit it makes validation and if everything is ok it sends data to third-party site and card payment is done on that site and mail is sent to owner of the site that transaction has been made. Now I want to add another submit button that only send email.
I have form like this:

```
<form name="bookingForm" class="cmxform" id="bookingForm" method="post"  action="third-party-site.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

and then I have fields like name, e-mail etc.

and submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="PROCEED TO BOOKING" name="submit1" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Click here to submit!"/>
```

So I tried this:

```
$('#submitButton2').click(function(){
$('form[name=bookingForm]').setAttrib('action','send_mail.php');
$('form[name=bookingForm]').submit();
});
```

and this:

```
$('#submitButton2').click(function(){
$('#bookingForm').attr('action', 'send_mail.php');
});
```

but nothing works. So if somebody can help me I would appreciate it.

Now i added script that validate on submit click and I added process.php which sends mail. Validations is ok but when it needs to be proceeded to process.php it gives an error because it constantly adds domain name in front of path to process.php.
Process.php is located inside theme folder and I defined path to like publichtml/pagename.com/wp/content/themes/mytheme/process.php and in console it says page can not be found
http://www.example.com/publichtml/pagename.com/wp/content/themes/mytheme/process.php.

---

Now i made ajax call so it sends email on another button.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
$('#submit2').removeAttr('disabled');



$('#bookingForm').validate({
    debug: true,
    //submitHandler: ajaxSubmit
            rules: {

            },
            messages: {
                first_name: "First name field required.",
                last_name: "Last name field required.",
                email: {
                    required: "Email address required",
                    email: "Email address must be in the format name@domain.com."                        
                }


            }

});

$('#submit2').click( function() {
    if( $('#bookingForm').valid() ) {
            ajaxSubmit();
    }
    else {
        $('label.error').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    }
});

});

function ajaxSubmit() {

$('#bookingForm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var firstName = $('#first_name').val();
var lastName = $('#last_name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();


var data = 'firstName=' +firstName+ '&lastName=' +lastName+ '&email='  +email;

$.ajax({
    url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        if( response.error != 'true' ) {
            $('#loading, #bookingForm, .message').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#response').html('<h3>Message sent successfully!    </h3>').fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else {
                $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#submit2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#response').html('<h3>There was a problem sending mail!</h3>').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#submit2').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#response').text('Error Thrown: ' +errorThrown+ '<br>jqXHR: ' +jqXHR+ '<br>textStatus: ' +textStatus ).show();
    }
});
return false;
}
```

and my process.php :

```
<?php

sleep(2);
define('TO', 'example.mail@mail.com');
define('FROM', $_POST['email']);
define('SUBJECT', 'inquiry');
$isValid = true;
$return = array("error" => "false");
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
global $return;
if ( sendEmail() ) {
    //return "Message sent successfully!";
    echo json_encode($return);
}
else {
    echo json_encode($return);
}
}
function sendEmail() {
    global $return;
    $body = "";
    $body .= "From: ".$_POST['email']."\nSubject: " . 'inquiry';
    $body .= "\nFirst Name: ".$_POST['first_name'];
    $body .= "\nLast Name: " .$_POST['lastName'];

    if ( @mail( TO, 'inquiry', $body ) ) {
    //if(true) {
        $return['error'] = 'false';
    }
    else {
            $return['error'] = 'true';
    }
    return $return;
    }
```

but I can not get values?
Anybody knows where I made mistake?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? - And where is your "#submitButton2" ? I can only the 1

Comment: Presumably you have added `<input type="submit" id="submitButton2" ...`

Comment: Yes, I added 2nd button with id submitButton2 and I made send_mail.php which should send mail. It is input like submitbutton1

Comment: So if I try 1st option (.setAttrib on click) then I get console error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setAttrib is not a function
and if I try 2nd option there is no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed type to get and now it works.

```
$body .= "\nFirst Name: ".$_GET['firstName'];
```

So to have 2 action on 1 form just add second button and post it to php.

Answer (score 0):

While clicking on the Submit Button 2, the form will be submitted before updating the *action*. So the result would be Same Action Page for both the buttons. You can use the *preventDefault();* to prevent the form being submitted on click. Here is a working code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="bookingForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Payment" name="s1" id='s1'>
    <input type="submit" value="Email" name="s2" id='s2'>
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('#s2').click(function(e){
        alert('hi');
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#bookingForm').attr('action', 'send_mail.php');
       $('#bookingForm').submit();
     });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing happens. No console error and nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure that the *#submitButton2'.click* event is triggered? Try alert something and post the result here.

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed that you're using one submit button and the button. So this won't be an issue. But this should work then. You're using a button for the second option. So just add * $('#bookingForm').submit();* to your code.

Comment: Hm...I tried this but it do not send mail. It alerts hi but do not submit form. If this can help:
this is wordpress theme. All files are in theme directory so is booking-form.php template and send_mail.php. I tried calling send-mail, send_mail.php and ../send_mail.php but nothing happens.

Comment: You can check the *developer tools* *network* panel to see whether the form is submitted or not. I submitted please check the response.